# Different PostgreSQL versions

Tags: postgresql, development-environment, production-environment

As a developer I use the PostgreSQL database system to store data in.
I am working on different projects, for different customers and running on different production machines. Some projects run version 8.4 and others 9.1. I expect more version differences.

What is the best way to avoid running into problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install multiple versions in parallel, and use the version matching what the customer has for that customer's project.

http://apt.postgresql.org/ and http://yum.postgresql.org/ will help a lot.